# How to robustly store bits of text for later use

Tags: macros, environments

I'm trying to write myself a package, similar to the exercise package, so I can prepare problem sets for my students. I wish to delay the output of problems and/or solutions until a suitable place in the document has been reached. I have something that sort of works but it's kind of clunky. For example, this works pretty well:

```
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{testb}{\global\expandafter\let\csname bar\endcsname\BODY}
```

I use `\csname` because the names are dynamically generated. This doesn't work so well if the command is anything other than `\BODY`. For example, if I do `\let\bar{\BODY}`, latex has an aneurysm (it binds `\bar` to just {).

There is an alternate way of doing this, which is:

```
\NewEnviron{testc}{\global\expandafter\edef\csname foo\endcsname{\BODY}}
```

This sort of works. The following thing works:
`\begin{testc}hi\end{testc}`, but this gives LaTeX an aneurysm: `\begin{testc}\bf hi\end{testc}`. (The error message is `\incomplete`). I tried to debug it myself but I get hopelessly tangled up in packages that I don't understand. If you do it with `\tiny` instead of `\bf` you get the wildly different LaTeX error message: `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].`

How can I squirrel away for later, not just `\BODY`, but some sophisticated combination of `\BODY` and other stuff, while having it robust to what's between the begin and end?

Edit: ok multiple solutions below

Comment: Why not use `\def`? `\let` does what it should do: use the the next token.

Comment: If you mean this: `\NewEnviron{testc}{\global\expandafter\def\csname foo\endcsname{\BODY}}`, I get: `! Undefined control sequence.
\foo ->\BODY`

Comment: I'm not sure why you don't like `\global\expandafter\let\csname bar\endcsname\BODY`: it's entirely normal TeX.

Comment: I started writing a class file to prepare conference programmes using the same sort of "save text for later" features. https://github.com/scmbradley/schedule I have just realised that this was six years ago. My god. Six years!?

Comment: You should definitely use \let with \BODY, \def with anything whose definition doesn't change, and \edef with things that do change (and you don't mind expanding them).

Comment: What about  `\NewEnviron{testc}{\global\expandafter\def\csname foo\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\BODY}}` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `\unexpanded` you can avoid worrying about `\protected@xdef`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\NewEnviron{exercise}{%
  \xdef\savedexercises{%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\savedexercises}%
    \noexpand\begin{printedexercise}%
    \unexpanded\expandafter{\BODY}%
    \noexpand\end{printedexercise}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\printexercises}{%
  \savedexercises
  \gdef\savedexercises{}%
}
\newcommand{\savedexercises}{}

\newtheorem{printedexercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

Here we talk about addition and show that $1+1=2$.

\begin{exercise}
Compute $1+2$
\end{exercise}

Here we talk about integrals.

\begin{exercise}
Compute the following integrals:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$

\item $\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{e^t}{t}\,dt$, for $t>0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{exercise}

Now we can print the exercises.

\printexercises

\end{document}
```

I used `\newtheorem` just for the example.

[image]

With `xparse` released 2019-03-05 or later:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{+b}
 {
  \tl_gput_right:Nn \g_loisel_exercises_tl
   {
    \begin{printedexercise}
    #1
    \end{printedexercise}
   }
 }{}

\NewDocumentCommand{\printexercises}{}
 {
  \tl_use:N \g_loisel_exercises_tl
  \tl_gclear:N \g_loisel_exercises_tl
 }

\tl_new:N \g_loisel_exercises_tl

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newtheorem{printedexercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

Here we talk about addition and show that $1+1=2$.

\begin{exercise}
Compute $1+2$
\end{exercise}

Here we talk about integrals.

\begin{exercise}
Compute the following integrals:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$

\item $\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{e^t}{t}\,dt$, for $t>0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{exercise}

Now we can print the exercises.

\printexercises

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh this is good

Answer (score 6):

If you want `BODY` to be saved then add stuff dynamically, you are likely best using two macros:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\NewEnviron{testb}{%
  \global\expandafter\let\csname bar\endcsname\BODY
  \expandafter\xdef\csname barplus\endcsname{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname bar\endcsname
    \noexpand\bf Hi
  }%
}
\begin{document}

\begin{testb}
  \bfseries
  Hi
\end{testb}
\show\barplus
\end{document}
```

If you want to avoid using `\BODY` you could use `xparse`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentEnvironment{testb}{+b}{\expandafter\gdef\csname bar\endcsname{#1}}{}
\begin{document}

\begin{testb}
  \bfseries
  Hi
\end{testb}
\show\bar
\end{document}
```

Comment: This needs TL'19 or up-to-date MiKTeX: this is a new feature in `xparse`.

Comment: Ah, thanks for this. By the way, I just tried this: `\NewEnviron{testc}{\expandafter\protected@xdef\csname foo\endcsname{\BODY}}
`, and it seems to work. Is there any situation where this would break again?

Comment: @SébastienLoisel Well if you have anything that's not LaTeX2e robust, yes, but that is nowadays quite a low risk.

Comment: What's an example of something not LaTeX2e robust?

Comment: Nevermind, I tried with \begin{itemize}...\end{itemize} and it broke.

Comment: Do you mean `xparse` has now the capability of storing the whole environment's content? That's amazing news (for me `:-)`).

Comment: @campa https://www.texdev.net/2019/03/07/collecting-environment-content-using-xparse

Answer (score 0):

A trick for triggering expansion is using `\romannumeral`:

When due to `\romannumeral` (La)TeX does gather together a sequence of digits trailed by a space as the number which it has to convert, expandable tokens get expanded.

When in the end a number is gathered together which is not positive, as the result of the conversion (La)TeX will not deliver any token at all.

Thus one can nicely (ab?)use `\romannumeral` for triggering a lot of expansion-work and flipping-arguments-around-work as long as one ensures that in the end `\romannumeral` will not find a positive number.

Here is a variant of [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/480302/118714) which does with `\romannumeral` and `\exchange` instead of `\xdef` and `\unexpanded`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

\NewEnviron{exercise}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\expandafter\savedexercises\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\BODY}{%
      \exchange{ }{\expandafter}\savedexercises
      \begin{printedexercise}%
    }%
    \end{printedexercise}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\printexercises}{%
  \savedexercises
  \gdef\savedexercises{}%
}
\newcommand{\savedexercises}{}

\newtheorem{printedexercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

Here we talk about addition and show that $1+1=2$.

\begin{exercise}
Compute $1+2$
\end{exercise}

Here we talk about integrals.

\begin{exercise}
Compute the following integrals:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$

\item $\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{e^t}{t}\,dt$, for $t>0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{exercise}

Now we can print the exercises.

\printexercises

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you wish to wrap the name of the macro that is to be defined into `\csname`..`\endcsname`, i.e., if you wish to use `\csname savedexercises\endcsname` rather than `\savedexercises`, you can take advantage of the fact that (La)TeX does expand expandable tokens while due to `\csname` gathering the name of a control sequence token and hereby searching for the matching `\endcsname`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}

\newcommand\exchange[2]{#2#1}

\NewEnviron{exercise}{%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname savedexercises\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{%
    \romannumeral0\expandafter\exchange\expandafter{\BODY}{%
      \exchange{ }{\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter}\csname savedexercises\endcsname
      \begin{printedexercise}%
    }%
    \end{printedexercise}%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\printexercises}{%
  \csname savedexercises\endcsname
  \expandafter\gdef\csname savedexercises\endcsname{}%
}
\expandafter\newcommand\expandafter{\csname savedexercises\endcsname}{}

\newtheorem{printedexercise}{Exercise}

\begin{document}

Here we talk about addition and show that $1+1=2$.

\begin{exercise}
Compute $1+2$
\end{exercise}

Here we talk about integrals.

\begin{exercise}
Compute the following integrals:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$

\item $\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{e^t}{t}\,dt$, for $t>0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{exercise}

Now we can print the exercises.

\printexercises

\end{document}
```

[image]

Be aware that with the approaches presented by now you cannot use `\printexercises` for having exercises occur in arbitrary places. You can have exercises occur only in places of the document which in the source correspond to places behind the exercise-environments.

Perhaps an environment which does read its content under verbatim-catcode-régime for unexpanded-writing it to .aux-file in a way where from the .aux-file it gets read back under verbatim-catcode-régime  also for defining a macro where `\scantokens` will be applied to, and thus some sort of re-implementation of the `\label`-`\ref`-mechanism or of the `\tableofcontents`-mechanism for verbatimized stuff might make it possible to make exercises printable throughout the entire document.

Implementing such a mechanism might be a nice challenge. But before taking that into consideration at all, exact information is needed on the intended usage and the desired "user-interface", i.e., what additional things you wish to be able to specify in which ways, etc, ...

Answer (score 0):

Another variant, using `filecontentsdef v1.4`, Supports `verbatim` content (if necessary).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontentsdef,pgffor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\newtheorem{exercise}{Exercise}
% savedexercise
\newcounter{exeNr}
\newenvironment{savedexercise}
{\stepcounter{exeNr}%
\begingroup
\filecontentsdefmacro{exercise-\the\value{exeNr}}}%
{\endfilecontentsdefmacro\endgroup}
\newcommand{\printexercise}[1]{\filecontentsexec{exercise-\the\numexpr#1\relax}}
\newcommand{\printsrcexercise}[1]{\filecontentsprint{exercise-\the\numexpr#1\relax}}

\begin{document}
\section{Talk about math}
Here we talk about addition and show that $1+1=2$.

\begin{savedexercise}
Compute $1+2$
\end{savedexercise}

Here we talk about integrals.

\begin{savedexercise}
Compute the following integrals:
\begin{itemize}
\item $\displaystyle\int_0^x e^{-t^2}\,dt$

\item $\displaystyle\int_1^x \frac{e^t}{t}\,dt$, for $t>0$.
\end{itemize}
\end{savedexercise}

\section{The exercises}
Now we can print the exercises.

\foreach \i in {1,...,2} {
\begin{exercise}
\printexercise{\i}
\end{exercise}
}

\section{The src exercises}
Now we can print the src of exercises.

\foreach \i in {1,...,2} {
\printsrcexercise{\i}
}

\section{Back to first exercises}
Remember the first exercise

\setcounter{exercise}{0}
\begin{exercise}
\printexercise{1}
\end{exercise}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of the output obtained]